# Website/URL Validation Regex in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, validation, url

I need a regex string to match URL starting with "http://", "https://", "www.", "google.com"

the code i tried using is:

```
//Pattern to check if this is a valid URL address
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(http://|https://)(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?");
    Matcher m;
    m=p.matcher(urlAddress);
```

but this code only can match url such as "http://www.google.com"

I know this ma be a dupicate question but i have tried all of the regex provided and it does not suit my requirement. Willl someone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Is your requirement that the url must start with either one of these `"http://"` `"https://"` `"www."` `"google.com"` ?

Comment: No. not only google website. the google.com is jus an exampl for websites without "www." or any "http or https" in their url.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to make `(http://|https://)` part in your regex as optional one.

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vM7wT6/2)

Comment: even more simpler `^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?$`

Comment: correct is `^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}\.([a-z]+)?$`

Comment: This regex does not accept slash eg. `https://www.google.com/123`.
It also does not accept multiple key value pairs, Eg: `https://www.google.com?key1=value1&&key2=value2`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the Apache commons library(org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator) for validating a url:

```
String[] schemes = {"http","https"}.
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);
```

And use :-

```
 urlValidator.isValid(your url)
```

Then there is no need of regex.

Link:-
   https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html

Comment: You might need a regex to avoid an exception if someone tries to enter "http:\\" or "http:/"

Comment: this validator doesn't allow underscore in host names

Answer (score 9):

If you use Java, I recommend use this RegEx (I wrote it by myself):

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([\w]+\.)+[‌​\w]{2,63}\/?$
"^(https?:\\/\\/)?(www\.)?([\\w]+\\.)+[‌​\\w]{2,63}\\/?$" // as Java-String
```

to explain:

- ^ = line start
- (https?://)? = "http://" or "https://" may occur.
- (www.)? = "www." may orrur.
- ([\w]+.)+ = a word ([a-zA-Z0-9]) has to occur one or more times. (extend here if you need special characters like ü, ä, ö or others in your URL - remember to use IDN.toASCII(url) if you use special characters. If you need to know which characters are legal in general: https://kb.ucla.edu/articles/what-characters-can-go-into-a-valid-http-url
- [‌​\w]{2,63} = a word ([a-zA-Z0-9]) with 2 to 63 characters has to occur exactly one time. (a TLD (top level domain (for example .com) can not be shorter than 2 or longer than 63 characters)
- /? = a "/"-character may occur. (some people or servers put a / at the end... whatever)
- $ = line end

-

If you extend it by special characters it could look like this:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([\w\Q$-_+!*'(),%\E]+\.)+[‌​\w]{2,63}\/?$
"^(https?:\\/\\/)?(www\.)?([\\w\\Q$-_+!*'(),%\\E]+\\.)+[‌​\\w]{2,63}\\/?$" // as Java-String
```

---

The answer of Avinash Raj is not fully correct.

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?$
```

The dots are not escaped what means it matches with any character. Also my version is simpler and I never heard of a domain like "test..com" (which actually matches...)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vM7wT6/279

---

Edit:
As I saw some people needing a regex which also matches servers directories I wrote this:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\w\Q$-_+!*'(),%\E]+\.)+(\w{2,63})(:\d{1,4})?([\w\Q/$-_+!*'(),%\E]+\.?[\w])*\/?$
```

while this may not be the best one, since I didn't spend too much time with it, maybe it helps someone. You can see how it works here: https://regex101.com/r/vM7wT6/700
It also matches urls like "hello.to/test/whatever.cgi"

Answer (score 3):

Java compatible version of @Avinash's answer would be

```
//Pattern to check if this is a valid URL address
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(http://|https://)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?$");
Matcher m;
m=p.matcher(urlAddress);
boolean matches = m.matches();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern="w{3}\.[a-z]+\.?[a-z]{2,3}(|\.[a-z]{2,3})"
```

this will only accept addresses like e.g www.google.com & www.google.co.in

Answer (score -1):

//I use that

```
static boolean esURL(String cadena){

    boolean bandera = false;

    bandera = cadena.matches("\\b(https://?|ftp://|file://|www.)[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");

    return bandera;
}
```